# Second ENI in AWS VPC is not accessible on Ubuntu instance

Tags: ubuntu, networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I'm just getting into VPC, trying to understand how everything works. So far the biggest hurdle I've run into is that any time I add a second Elastic NIC to a machine, that second IP is not accessible by any others in the VPC.  Here's what I did

- Launched Canonical provided AMI for Ubuntu 12.10 x64 EBS.
- During launch I configured it for two network interfaces (same subnet)
- Once the machine was up, I added the following to /etc/network/interfaces :

> auto eth1
>
> iface eth1 inet dhcp

- *ifup eth1*
- Run *ifconfig*, verify the second address is up.

On my primary (internet accessible) instance:

- ping (IP for new instance eth0) - Works
- ping (IP for new instance eth1) - FAILS

There are no ACL's that prevent ping, as it works with eth0.  There is no firewall setup on the machine.  I've tried 4 different instances across several SGs and AZs with multiple interfaces, all with the same result.

I've been bashing my head against the wall for longer than I care to admit on this.  I cannot figure out where the error is on this.

Comment: What's your route table look like before and after you add the ENI?

Comment: You ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @user160576 Nope.  I gave up and just did everything on eth0.  Since eth0 actually is an internal IP, you can use that as both your internal and your external network interface for routing. I was thinking more along the classic lines of eth0 = ethernet cable to DSL model and eth1 = ethernet cable to local switch. That's not really the case here.

Comment: Why are both ENIs in the same subnet? That doesnt get you anything

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The routing table by default will only route traffic to `eth0`.
Even though ubuntu detects the other ENI, you still have to route traffic to it.

You'll have to do some advanced routing:

**1) Enabling access to 2nd ENI immediately and temporarily.**

source: http://www.rjsystems.nl/en/2100-adv-routing.php

```bash
# this will show your route table, i'll assume you have eth0 and eth1
# and your default is for eth0 to point to the gateway
# for this example lets assume the following:
# eth0 = 192.168.100.5 
# eth1 = 192.168.100.10
# gateway = 192.168.100.1
ip route show ;

# first step is to create a routing table for your new device
cat /etc/iproute2/rt_tables ;
echo 2 eth1_rt >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables ;

# next add the eth1_rt route table, so by default it will also point to the gateway
ip route add default via 192.168.100.1 dev eth1 table eth1_rt ;

# next take a look at your ip rules
# i'll assume the defaults here, and things flows to default with priority 32767
ip rule;

# let's add a rule, if we see traffic from eth1's IP address,
# use its new routing table we setup, and give it higher priority than default
ip rule add from 192.168.100.10 lookup eth1_rt prio 1000 ;

# done! now check your traffic from both IPs, they should both work.
```

**2) Enabling access to 2nd ENI on reboot but persistently.**

source: http://blog.bluemalkin.net/multiple-ips-and-enis-on-ec2-in-a-vpc/

Additionally, if you want this change to persist, you can make all these changes in the interface file and just restart the network service or reboot for it to take effect.

```bash
# NOTE: add the eth1_rt routing table to /etc/iproute2/rt_tables as show in previous section

# original config to make dchp, I add mine to /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth1.cfg
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dchp
    # your extra rules for eth1
    up ip route add default via 192.168.100.1 dev eth1 table eth1_rt
    up ip rule add from 192.168.100.10 lookup eth1_rt prio 1000
```

For this to take full effect, reboot the system.

**NOTE:** I tried `/etc/init.d/networking restart;` but it didn't pick up the route/rule changes, not sure why, so I had reboot.  In the event you want to make it immediate and persistent, do both methods.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it.
I use static IP.
Initially I use dhcp to get 2 items. The IP address and the netmask.
Here is the step by step instruction:

boot the instance

```
sudo cp /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0.cfg /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth1.cfg
sudo sed -i "s/eth0/eth1/g" /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth1.cfg
sudo ifdown eth1
sudo ifup eth1
sudo ifconfig eth1 | tee /tmp/ifconfig-eth1-output.txt
sudo ifdown eth1
sudo rm -f /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth1.cfg 
ETH0_IP=$(cat /tmp/ifconfig-eth1-output.txt | grep "inet addr:" | cut -f 2 -d':' | cut -f 1 -d' ')
ETH0_NETMASK=$(cat /tmp/ifconfig-eth1-output.txt| grep "inet addr:" | cut -f 4 -d':')
ETH0_GATEWAY=$(echo ${ETH0_IP} | sed "s/[0-9]*$/1/g")
echo "auto eth1" > /tmp/eth1.cfg
echo "iface eth1 inet static" >> /tmp/eth1.cfg  
echo "address ${ETH0_IP}" >> /tmp/eth1.cfg 
echo "netmask ${ETH0_NETMASK}" >> /tmp/eth1.cfg 
echo "up ip route add default via ${ETH0_GATEWAY} dev eth1 table 1  metric 10001" >> /tmp/eth1.cfg 
echo "up ip rule add from ${ETH0_IP}/32 table 1 priority 10001" >> /tmp/eth1.cfg 
echo "up ip route flush cache" >> /tmp/eth1.cfg 
sudo cp -f /tmp/eth1.cfg /etc/network/interfaces.d/
sudo ifup eth1
```

that should do it, run these to check.

```
curl --silent http://ipinfo.io
curl --interface eth0 --silent http://ipinfo.io
curl --interface eth1 --silent http://ipinfo.io
```

these would take immediate effect and will persist through reboots.